# Como contar o número de tabelas no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou tentando contar o número de tabelas existentes em um banco de dados MySQL.

Tentei fazer da forma abaixo, porém retornou um erro de sintaxe:

```
SELECT COUNT(SHOW TABLES)
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
USE databasename; SHOW TABLES; SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/CountTable.sql).

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5201025/221800).

Comment: Em poucas palavras, novamente